# Duality in conic quadratic programming for good deal measure

Tags: optimization, coherent-risk-measure

I am working on a problem relating to what is known as the "Good Deal risk measure" for production valuation in incomplete markets. I have created the following primal optimization problem, and I am wondering how it can be converted to its dual formulation. I am mainly curios since this is a quadratic conic program, and so I am unsure how the quadratic constraint is handled. just FYI, N_(t-1) can be viewed as the nodes in a scenario tree at time step t-1, whilst N_(t-1)m are the nodes at time t which are descendant of node m at time t-1. The delta term is the probability of reaching node n at time t from node m at time t-1.

[image: Here is the primal conic program]

I tried to follow the standard rules of duality from linear programming, but the result does not make sense from a financial viewpoint (the dual variable for the last constraint becomes indexed on t-1, but it should be t, but dont want to go too much into specifics). FYI, the original inspiration for this formulation can be found in *Beyond Arbitrage: Good‐Deal Asset Price Bounds in Incomplete Markets* or *Good-Deal Investment Valuation in Stochastic Generation Capacity Expansion Problems*.